# if check box is checked hide checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have laravel blade where I am updating a DB value using checkbox. I want if a user check that checkbox it should be either hidden on click or disabled  but nothing works. What mistake i am making? or i should try any other method?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '.js-switch', function() {
    let received_amount = $(this).prop('checked') === true ? 1 : 0;
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == 0) {
      $(this).closest('tr').addClass('cancel');
    } else {
      $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('cancel');
    }
    let userId = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "url",
      data: {
        'received_amount': received_amount,
        'user_id': userId
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.message);
      }
    });
    $(".red").show();
    $(this).hide()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Received Subtotal</span> <input type="checkbox" data-id="1" name="equal_order" value="red" class="red"></label>
```

Comment: I removed a }) too many

Comment: Too many issues
1. What is js-switch, 2. invalid HTML, where is the table, where is the <label> to match </label> - please update the snippet I made with RELEVANT CSS, HTML and Script. We are not debugging Laravel here, so no {{}} please but add Bootstrap relevant libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this using the attribute "disabled".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#checkbox1').click(function() {
    $(this).attr("disabled", true);
  });
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Lundstromski/pen/zYqNNVG)